# Why a != b != c is not equal to a != b and a != c and b != c?

Tags: python

I want to check if 3 values a, b , c are not equal to each other.
Given that a == b == c equals to a == b and b == c and a == c, why does python give a different answer for a != b != c ?

Thanks!

This is a task from an introductory course to Python:

"How many of the three integers a, b, c are equal?"

This is a simple task and I got the correct answer with the following:

```
a = int(input()); b = int(input()); c = int(input());

if a != b and a != c and b != c:
    print(0)
elif a == b == c:
    print(3)
else:
    print(2)
```

Yet, I can not understand why `a != b != c` wouldn't do the job in the initial if statement.

From `a != b != c` I expect the same as from `a != b and a != c and b != c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `a != b != c` you are actually using chained comparison, from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> Formally, if a, b, c, …, y, z are expressions and op1, op2, …, opN are
>   comparison operators, then a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z is equivalent to
>   a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z, except that each expression is
>   evaluated at most once.

So `a != b != c` is actually `a != b and b != c`, which is different from `a != b and a != c and b != c`, for example:

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 1
print(a != b != c)
print(a != b and a != c and b != c)
```

**Output**

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 1):

The "equals" operator is transitive:

> if a == b and b == c, then a == c

The "not equals" operator is not:

> if a != b and b != c, a could still equal c

Why? Take

> a = 3, b = 4, c = 3

Then

> a != b, b != c, but a == c

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work in one expression you can just do:

```
print(a != b != c != a)
```

This should allow you to stay away from any scary-looking "and" statements.

Comment: Even if your answer might be correct, the question was expecting an explanation of why the results of the 2 expressions are different (i.e I assume they wanted to understand python internal)